# ImageMagick Transparent PNG Background

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am trying to take this image, [image] which I converted to a .png file and then want to remove the white background to make it transparent.

I have tried running the following but haven't had any luck.

```
    $strInputFile = 'car.png';
    $execScript = '/usr/local/bin/convert '.$strInputFile.' ';
    $execScript .= "-transparent white car-new.png"; 
    $output = shell_exec($execScript);
```

Am I doing something wrong? The new file gets created, but still has the white background.

Answer (score 30):

Similar problem with php imagick:

When converting SVG to transparent PNG, dont forget to put this BEFORE $imagick->readImageBlob():

```
$imagick->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
```

Comment: I had same problem and the above suggestion helped me get a little further. However now the png file generated have black background. :(

Comment: So after a lot of trial and error, i realized that i was using $im->adaptiveSharpenImage(2,1); in my php code after setbackgroundColor method and this appeared to create a non transparent background. After removing that method, i could get png transparent backgrounds. Now to figure out how to get sparp, crisp and complete png images from svg. :) Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: `dont forget to put this BEFORE `

MUST BE GIVEN IN BOLD. saved several hours !!

Comment: In extra bold, or even heavy or black, with an extended display typeface!

Answer (score 4):

As the image is a JPEG, which is subject to losses and slight colour inaccuracies, the whites in your image are not actually 100% pure white. ImageMagick has a way of dealing with this through the `-fuzz` setting which allows a degree of fuzziness, or a range of allowable error, when specifying colours.

The correct incantation here is:

```
convert car.jpg -fuzz 10% -transparent white car.png
```

Comment: With a few attempts I got a perfect result with: `convert source.png -fuzz 4% -transparent white result.png`. `10%` was eating too many pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code:

```
$strInputFile = 'car.png';
$target = 'car_transparent.png';
$im = new Imagick($strInputFile);
$im->paintTransparentImage($im->getImageBackgroundColor(), 0, 10000);
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$im->writeImage($target);
$im->destroy();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to use [`-transparency`](http://amath.colorado.edu/computing/software/man/convert.html) rather than `-transparent`?

Comment: I tried using -transparency white and the new file doesn't even get created now.

Comment: Have you tried running the command by hand on the system? Or failing that, echoed the value of `$output` so you can see if there's an error  message?

Comment: echoing $output gives me this `/usr/local/bin/convert /var/www/html/test/car.png -transparency white /var/www/html/test/car-new.png`

Comment: That looks more like you echo'd `$execScript`, not `$output`.

Comment: When I tried, `$output = shell_exec($execScript); echo $output;` nothing happened. The page was blank.

Answer (score 0):

The background of your image is not `white` (I mean 0xFFFFFF), it's 0xFEFEFE. Try:

```
$execScript .= "-transparent #FEFEFE car-new.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not making a Shell script, then try this:

```
$ convert -transparency white car.png car-new.png
```

This should work in a generic terminal. If it doesn't, let me know. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The order of doing things is important. First set background, then load data

```
$svg = new Imagick();

// Important! First set Background color transparent, then read svg
$svg->setBackgroundColor('transparent');
$svg->readImage($svgPath);
```